# How to convieve of a cross platform python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a python interactive script project containing a few directories with project files and a main python script.

The script does the work of batch processing scientific images for biological systematics.

I wrote os agnostic code, but I was thinking about trying to package/freeze the script as a cli utility that a (more or less)lay person could download and use.

I have been reading about packaging and freezing techniques in python and the more I read the more I feel I'm confused. (I'm linux user)

**Am I conceiving of this script as a utility correctly? Is is worth it/possible to pass command line args to an .exe, and should I package/freeze the files for this kind of interactive cli script?**

I don't have a lot of experience with windows. I'm looking for advice/pointer where to look next/search.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path, but you need to understand a little more about python packaging to know how to proceed.

You are right that you need to package your code with setup tools. This will make it cake to install the package for others and will let python decide where to properly put things. **-including script utilities/non-code files-**

**Setuptools has special support built in JUST FOR SCRIPTS! that will let you pass arguments, ect..**

However, in packaging the code, you must understand that what you are really doing is making it a library that can be installed with pip. Therefore, that python script utility that you wrote will be treated as a library by setuptools. Setuptools will have you make a separate script file to import your new library and call the script `main()` function.

I know that you were already using [this manual](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and that's fantastic. Everything you need to first set up and understand a python package is in there. RTFM up a storm.

As I understand it, you can then look more into freezing the package (and register it with Pypi) for other systems once you have a handle on packaging.

note: use `scripts` keyword in setup tools to specify your script